# Retrieve a next record in a list ordered by DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider the following list of dates

```
ID  NAME    DATE
1   Mary    01-01-1901
2   Mary    01-01-1901
3   Mary    01-01-1901
4   Mary    01-01-1901
5   Lucy    01-01-1951
6   Peter   01-01-1961
```

The above is a list ORDERED BY DATE. Hence in the database it is not represented like so.

I am trying to fetch the next record in the list BY DATE. What I am doing is, retrieving the list of 
persons from the database, then ordering by Date and then by ID. What is happening is that the 
IDs returned are always the same:

Next Record -> 2 -> Next Record -> 1 -> Next record 2 
and so on... It seems I am stuck on the first 2 records. I am using LINQ-to-SQL

Below is the code I am using to achieve this

```
string newID = dx.Persons
                              .AsEnumerable()
                              .ToList()
                              .Where(
                                x => x.DOB.CompareTo(newConvertedValue) == 0 && x.Id > currentID
                                 ||
                                x.DOB.CompareTo(newConvertedValue) > 0 && x.Id != currentID)
                              .OrderBy(x => x.DOB)
                              .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
                              .Select(x => x.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                              .First();
```

For me it makes no sense to order the list after specifying the Where conditions, but when i tried to modify
the statement I got a no element in sequence exception.

Please note that the variables stated above have the following meanings:
newConvertedvalue = date of birth of the currently displayed record
currentID = ID of the currently displayed record.

I have tried using different solutions but I cannot seem to find a way to solve this.

I have implemented similar methods to sort and fetch next records for columns containing integers and strings,
which are working fine (Also thanks to the contribution from this great website). 
But this column containing Dates is giving me a hard time.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why don't you simply return back a string[] of id's by removing `.First()` and using `.ToArray()`? Then you can simply use a foreach or for statement to loop through each of the ids

Comment: You are aware that `dx.Persons.AsEnumerable()` (and additionally, the `.ToList()`) means that you have absorbed the *entire* table over the wire into memory? Shouldn't you be doing this *at the server*?

Comment: I simply need to fetch the next record from a list ordered by dates. I am using the ID to make sure that if the date is the same, it would fetch the record of the next immediate ID (by making sure it is greater than the one preceding it). I cannot just loop through each of the id's only as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var Ids = dx.Persons
          .AsEnumerable()
          .ToList()
          .Where(x => x.DOB.CompareTo(newConvertedValue) == 0 && x.Id > currentID
                                 ||
                 x.DOB.CompareTo(newConvertedValue) > 0 && x.Id != currentID)
          .OrderBy(x => x.DOB)
          .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
          .Select(x => new { ID = Id, Date = DOB })
          .ToList();

Ids.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ID));
```